# (SQL) Crystal Report, Linking two tables into one without breaking report, picture attached

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

Tables in Question

[image: Tables in Question]

I don't think I am going to be able to do what I am trying to, but thought it would be worth asking the question. In my point of sale system there is no report available for a specific type of order so I am writing a crystal report to be able to view the order type in question. Unfortunately the POS system only saves the document sequence field in one table. The document sequence is the number that is shown on a document when viewing it, all of the DocIDInternal numbers are gibberish that are not visible to employees when pulling up a document to view it.

I would like to be able to view the document sequence for both the order and the associated purchase order on my report, but I can not find a way to link both into the Documents table to access the document sequence without breaking the report. As far as I can tell I am able to link either the order or the purchase order to the document table, in order to view the document sequence field for one or the other. Neither the order table or the purchase order table contain the document sequence and it is only available through the documents table. I have searched and been unable to locate any other tables available to me that contain the document sequence field other than the documents table.

Comment: Could you elaborate upon how adding the link breaks the report?  Does it create duplication, does it stop returning data, does the data become incongruent?  Please describe exactly what happens when you link this table.

Comment: When linking the Purchasing table into my report it stops returning all data, I go from 150 results on my report to 0.

Comment: Link both orders to document table, using left joins. Filter out documents, which are not orders.

Answer (score 0):

If you open Database Expert and go to the Links tab where you took the screenshot above.  Double-click on the line linking your OrdersDtl and Document tables to edit the link.  On the left side is a set of radio buttons that define the type of join to use with the tables.  Try changing this value to "Left Outer Join" if the current selection is "Inner Join".  This should solve the problem with it breaking the report, but I suspect there is more to troubleshoot before you will have the data your want from the Document table.

When Inner Join is used as the type of join, if there are no records found on the Documents table that correspond to the value of DocIdInternal on the OrdersDtl table, then the query returns no rows.  When Left Outer Join is used, the query will always return all rows from the table on the left side of the join, even when no corresponding records are found on the right side of the join.

Once you have the report returning data again, now we need to determine why there are no records being linked from the Documents table.  To do this, I would place the DocIdInternal database field on your report so you can verify it has a value on the OrdersDtl table.  You may need to discuss this with your Database Administrator to determine if this is the proper way to link these tables.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, unfortunately the picture attached was for illustrative purposes, below is the command that I am using for this report and I am unsure of how to define a left join in the command line.

Comment: Select O.Name, 
D.DocYYMM, 
D.DocSeq, 
D.EntryUser, 
O.OrderDate, 
O.Subtotal, 
O.DirectPODocIDInternal, 
PH.DocIDInternal, 
PH.VendorName, 
PH.VendorPhone, 
OD.PODocIDInternal, 
OD.QtyOrdered, 
OD.QtySold, 
OD.QtyRemaining, 
OD.ItemNumber, 
OD.Description, 
OD.DetailID
                            
From Documents D (NOLOCK), OrdersHdr O (NOLOCK), OrdersDtl OD (NOLOCK), PurchaseOrderHdrs PH (NOLOCK)

Where D.DocIDInternal=O.DocIDInternal and
OD.DocIDInternal=O.DocIDInternal and
OD.PODocIDInternal=PH.DocIDInternal and
O.OrderType=4 and
D.DocStatus=0

Comment: For ease of reading, here is the Where portion of the command separated from the rest of the command, this does not have the Purchase Order table linked into the Documents:    Where D.DocIDInternal=O.DocIDInternal and OD.DocIDInternal=O.DocIDInternal and OD.PODocIDInternal=PH.DocIDInternal and O.OrderType=4 and D.DocStatus=0

Comment: The syntax of your SQL Command is using an implicit join.  This is an older way of joining data between tables that really isn't recommended today.  Implicit joins are essentially an Inner Join.  So I think you are still dealing with an issue where the structure of your join is preventing the query from returning any results.  I think the first step then is to convert your query into an explicit join.  However, I'm not sure how to handle your table hint for NOLOCK as the syntax used in your SQL command is unfamiliar to me.  I'm used to seeing it as "WITH (NOLOCK)".

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I was given about 20 minutes of instruction by a guy who came to set up our Point of Sale on how to write reports for Crystal and that is how he showed me to write them. If I switch over to the method using the tables and lines showing the joins how would I put in my OrderType and DocStatus filters? I haven't built a report using that method before due to not understanding how to create filters with it.

Comment: Parameter Fields would allow you to input filters at run-time.  When you have a parameter field on a report, when the report executes it will prompt the user to provide a value for the parameter.  Then you can use that parameter field in the report's Select Expert to filter the data returned.

Comment: I've started creating an order that has the Purchase Order table and Orders Header table linked into the Documents table via left joins. It give the same number of orders as my original report. Thank you for the help in that. What I now do not understand is how to differentiate when I want the Document Sequence field from the Documents table to pull the associated sequence from the Order table vs the associated sequence from the Purchase Order table. It is defaulting to showing the sequence associated with the Orders table.

Comment: I may have spoken a bit too soon, as soon as I bring in a field from the Purchase Order table into the report the number of records that are displayed drops to 0.

Comment: Crystal Report tries to link tables automatically, but I personally don't like that feature and turn it off in Options.  To toggle automatic linking, go to File > Options.  Then go to the Database tab and uncheck "Automatic Smart Linking".  It should be at the bottom of the window.  With this feature off, you can link your tables however you think is best by going into Database Expert, then go to the Links tab and drag and drop fields from one table to the other.  As for which fields to link, I really can't answer that without knowing how your database was designed.

Comment: Once you have the tables linked, double click the lines that connect the fields in each of your table and chance the radio button option on the left to "Left Inner Join".  That should stop the loss of data when you add a field from the PO table.  However, this sounds like the link between the fields may not be correct because the fact that your record count drops to zero indicates there is no data found on the PO table that correlates to the other table with the link you are using.  A screen shot of how your tables are linked may help me help you.